# RSpec undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rspec-rails

I am trying to test my Rails app. Now I am testing my tiny controller but I have a problem.
I use device to authentication.
My controller which I test is like,

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  #skip_before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :authenticate, :except=>[:disabled]

  def index
    @widgets = current_user.widgets.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @widgets }
    end
  end

  def new
    @widget = Widget.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @widget }
    end
  end

  def create
    @widget = Widget.new(params[:widget])
    @widget.user_id = current_user.id
    @widget.score = 0
    @widget.total_score = 0
    @widget.click_number = 0
    @widget.average = 0

    respond_to do |format|
      if @widget.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_widget_path(@widget), notice: 'Widget was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @widget, status: :created, location: @widget }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @widget.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        raise 'an error occurs when creation'
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @widget }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
  end

  def update
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @widget.update_attributes(params[:widget])
        format.html { redirect_to edit_widget_path(@widget), notice: 'Widget was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render json: @widget, status: :created, location: @widget }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @widget.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        raise 'there is an error when alteration'
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid]).destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to widgets_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  #generate widget
  def generate
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  rescue
    #TODO add widget not found page
    render :template => 'application/widget_not_found', :status => :not_found
  end



  protected

  def authenticate
    unless current_user
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

end
```

My route file maybe you can want to look in it.

```
Rwidget::Application.routes.draw do

  match 'widgets' => 'widgets#index', :via => :get
  match 'widgets/new' => 'widgets#new', :via => :get
  match 'widgets' => 'widgets#create', :via => :post
  match 'widgets/:uuid' => 'widgets#show', :via => :get
  get 'widgets/:uuid/edit' => 'widgets#edit'
  match 'widgets/:uuid' => 'widgets#update', :via => :put
  match 'widgets/:uuid' => 'widgets#destroy', :via => :delete

  resources :widgets, :collection => [:destroy]

  match 'rws/generate/:uuid' => 'rws#generate'

  get 'rws/:uuid' => 'rws#show'
  put 'rws/:uuid' => 'rws#update'
  post 'rws/getUserInfo' => 'rws#getUserInfo'

  resources :authentications
  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'

  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  root :to => "home#index"
```

And my controller_spec. rb is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe WidgetsController do
  login_user

  describe "User" do
    before(:each) do
      @current_user = mock_model(User, :id => 1)
      @widget = mock_model(Widget, :user_id => 1)
      Widget.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@current_user)
      Widget.stub!(:widgets).and_return(@widget)
    end

    it "should have a current_user" do
      subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
    end
  end

  def mock_widget(stubs={})
    @mock_widget ||= mock_model(Widget, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  describe "Get index" do
    it "should get all widgets " do
      Widget.stub(:all) { [mock_widget] }
      get :index
      assigns(:widgets) == @widgets
    end
  end

  describe "Post widget" do
    it "creates a new widget" do
      Widget.stub(:new).with({'these' => 'params'}) { mock_widget(:language => "en") }
      post :create, :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
      assigns(:widget) == @widgets
      response.should redirect_to (edit_widget_path(@mock_widget))
    end
  end

  describe "Get widget" do
    it "shows exact widget via id" do
      Widget.stub(:find).with("10") { [mock_widget] }
      get :show
      assigns(:mock_widget) == mock_widget
    end
  end

  describe "Put widget" do
    it "updates the widget attributes" do
      Widget.stub(:find).with("6") { [mock_widget] }
      mock_widget.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
      put :update, :id => "6", :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
    end
  end

  describe "delete destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested widget" do
      Widget.stub(:find).with("10") { [mock_widget] }
      mock_widget.should_receive(:destroy)
      get :destroy, :id => "10"
    end
  end
end
```

Any I configured my spec helper to devise settings.
My controller_macros.rb is

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = Factory(:user)
      #user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

And my spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
  config.include RequestMacros, :type => :request
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

end
```

Finally, my devise.rb that is under the support file,

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

So. When I debug my controller.spec file, there is no current_user in update and delete describe blocks.
When I run the `ender$ rspec spec/controllers/widgets_controller_spec.rb`
I face with

```
Failures:

  1) WidgetsController Put widget updates the widget attributes
     Failure/Error: put :update, :id => "6", :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:60:in `block in update'
     # ./app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:59:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/widgets_controller_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) WidgetsController delete destroy destroys the requested widget
     Failure/Error: get :destroy, :id => "10"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:72:in `destroy'
     # ./spec/controllers/widgets_controller_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.4569 seconds
6 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/widgets_controller_spec.rb:49 # WidgetsController Put widget updates the widget attributes
rspec ./spec/controllers/widgets_controller_spec.rb:57 # WidgetsController delete destroy destroys the requested widget
```

How I fix it?

**SOLUTION:**
I shifted findbyid to findbyuuid because of searching over uuid. After that, I need to return an array and I got it on this way,

```
Widget.stub(:find_by_uuid).with("6").and_return(mock_widget(:update_attributes => true))
```

It's done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spec you're doing

```
Widget.stub(:find).with("6")...
```

But your app code calls `Widget.find_by_uuid`. Your spec code should be stubbing out the calls your app code will do. Similarly, your app code is expecting `params[:uuid]` to be set but your spec is only `params[:id]`.

You should also return a correct return value - `find_by` returns a single object but the stub you are setting up returns an array.

```
Widget.stub(:find_by_uuid).with("6") { mock_widget}
```

Will make your stub return the mock widget rather than an array containing the mock widget

Comment: Can I do Widget.stub(:find_by_uuid).with("6")... ?

Comment: Try it!  You can stub any method - the method need not even exist.

Comment: Woov! it works thank you ! but now it returns Failure/Error: put :update, :id => "6", :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
       <Widget(id: integer, language: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, widget_type: string, widget_size: string, completed: boolean, user_id: integer, score: integer, uuid: string, total_score: integer, click_number: integer, average: integer) (class)> received :find_by_uuid with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("6")
              got: (nil)

Comment: Like I said your spec is passing the wrong parameters to your action (id instead of uuid)

Comment: describe "Put widget" do
    it "updates the widget attributes" do
      Widget.stub(:find_by_uuid).with("6") { [mock_widget] }
      mock_widget.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
      put :update, :uuid => "6", :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
    end
  end

Comment: ERROR: 
     Failure/Error: put :update, :uuid => "6", :widget => {'these' => 'params'}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `update_attributes' for [#<Widget:0x3fd4d59cf150 @name="Widget_1004">]:Array
     # ./app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:60:in `block in update'
     # ./app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:59:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/widgets_controller_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: See my answer - your stub is returning an array rather than a single object

Comment: so what should I do? I cannot get it what you mean

Comment: Don't return an array. So return just the object - see updated answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I got it and I updated my question with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to look at WidgetCOntroller#update to know on which object 'update_attributes' is getting called.

```
  def update
    @widget = Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @widget.update_attributes(params[:widget])
```

So, basically, this call is returning nil:

```
Widget.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
```

You can debug this using 'rails console'.

Comment: It is working on development area. When I test it, an error occurs that "undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass".